# How to send files with Sinch Instant Message?

Tags: sinch

I am developing a chat app and I am using Sinch SDK for JavaScript. My question is simple.

How can I send files through the Instant Message, to another user that I am chatting with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only text messages, no attachments.

Answer (score 0):

`Sinch` until now supported text only , therefore you can benefit from texting attachments between two devices.
Make your own API to upload files to your server when uploading is successfully done you can send `json` object to `sinch` client to tell him an file send successfully like this

```
{ "type":"image" , "value":"<your-url-image-in-your-server>"}
```

The receiver device can fetch this message and convert it from `text` to `json` object and receive the file from `value` attribute.
And you can do same for any type of files (Images - Sound - PDF ...etc).

I hope to help any one to use `Sinch` for sending attachments.